# Use Accelerometer in Unity Animator

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a scene in which character moves in x axis by Input.acceleration. It works fine but when I add a simple animator (character is a plane and animation is going up and down) to it, it just shows animation and doesn't move. should I add parameters to animator for going right and left? how to implement it in acceleration? Here is my code;

```
float movespeed=10f;
float dirx;

void Start () {

        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    }

void Update ()
    {
        rb.velocity=new Vector2 (dirx,0f);
    }
    void FixedUpdate (){
        dirx=Input.acceleration.x*movespeed;
        transform.position=new Vector2
(Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x,-7f,7f),transform.position.y);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume the x-movement is overridden by the animation value.

You can remove that value from the animation or handle the x-movement in `LateUpdate()`, this method is called after the animation is applied.